# Unable to create default trait implementation

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a vector math library that can generate SIMD optimized versions of a function based on the feature set supported by the processor. Currently I have a structure for each feature set and a trait that defines a fallback structure. I implement each operation on the feature set structure. I have not been able to implement the fallback mechanism. What I have now generates the flowing error.

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Add<Vec4, Vec4>` for type `Scalar`:
  --> src/main.rs:41:1
   |
14 | default impl<F: FeatureSet, Lhs, Rhs> Add<Lhs, Rhs> for F where <F as FeatureSet>::Fallback: Add<Lhs, Rhs> {
   | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
41 | impl Add<Vec4, Vec4> for Scalar {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Scalar`
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=eb4e791aa6bc4d94093b530826e51faa).

Example code:

```
#![feature(specialization)]
use std::arch::x86_64 as arch;

trait FeatureSet {
    type Fallback;
}

trait Add<Lhs, Rhs> {
    type Output;
    unsafe fn add(lhs: Lhs, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}

// Attempt at implementing fallback to implementation in Fallback type
default impl<F: FeatureSet, Lhs, Rhs> Add<Lhs, Rhs> for F where <F as FeatureSet>::Fallback: Add<Lhs, Rhs> {
    type Output = <<F as FeatureSet>::Fallback as Add<Lhs, Rhs>>::Output;
    unsafe fn add(lhs: Lhs, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output {
        <F as FeatureSet>::Fallback::add(lhs, rhs)
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
union Vec4 {
    scalar: std::mem::ManuallyDrop<[f32; 4]>,
    #[allow(unused)]
    simd: std::mem::ManuallyDrop<arch::__m128>,
}

impl std::convert::From<[f32; 4]> for Vec4 {
    fn from(values: [f32; 4]) -> Self {
        Self {
            scalar: std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(values)
        }
    }
}

struct Scalar;
impl FeatureSet for Scalar {
    type Fallback = ();
}

impl Add<Vec4, Vec4> for Scalar {
    type Output = Vec4;
    unsafe fn add(lhs: Vec4, rhs: Vec4) -> Self::Output {
        let mut r: [f32; 4] = std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init();
        for i in 0 .. 4 {
            r[i] = lhs.scalar[i] + rhs.scalar[i];
        }
        
        r.into()
    }
}

struct Sse;
impl FeatureSet for Sse {
    type Fallback = Scalar;
}

// Should fall back to implementation in FeatureSet::Fallback type when not implemented
impl Add<Vec4, Vec4> for Sse {
    type Output = Vec4;
    #[inline]
    #[target_feature(enable = "sse")]
    unsafe fn add(lhs: Vec4, rhs: Vec4) -> Self::Output {
        let r = arch::_mm_add_ps(*lhs.simd, *rhs.simd);
        Vec4 {
            simd: std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(r)
        }
    }
}

#[inline(never)]
// This function should be able to be specialized for each feature set for later
// runtime selection
unsafe fn perform_add<F: FeatureSet>(a: Vec4, b: Vec4) -> Vec4 {
    F::add(a, b)
}

fn main() {
    let a = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0].into();
    let b = [4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0].into();
    
    unsafe {
        let c = perform_add::<Sse>(a, b);
        println!("{} {} {} {}", c.scalar[0], c.scalar[1], c.scalar[2], c.scalar[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but [specialization is currently unsound](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844#issue-135807289), and you should switch to `min_specialization` instead (if possible).

Comment: I wish I could, but `min_specialization` does not appear to support associated types.